# How do I convert a string number value with a dollar sign to BigDecimal in java?

Tags: java, string, bigdecimal

I have a dollar amount in a String format.  For example: String salePrice = $348.00.

However, I want to convert this String value to a BigDecimal value, but it has a dollar sign in the string. I tried the code below but it isn't working.

```
BigDecimal sPrice = new BigDecimal(salePrice);
```

I ended up getting this exception below:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The [BigDecimal Constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) take a valid numerical string.

> The String representation consists of an optional sign,
>   '+' ('\u002B') or '-' ('\u002D'), followed by a sequence of zero or
>   more decimal digits ("the integer"), optionally followed by a
>   fraction, optionally followed by an exponent.

```
String salePrice = "$348.00";
String price = salePrice.replace("$","");
BigDecimal sPrice = new BigDecimal(price);
System.out.println(sPrice);
```

Output = `348.00`

You can also look at [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) class. Using this class you can set your corresponding `Locale`.

```
String salePrice = "$123.45";
Locale locale = Locale.US;
Number number = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale).parse(salePrice);
System.out.println(number);
```

Output = `123.45`

Comment: what if the string value is null or "". my setproperty accepts only bigDecimal.

Comment: You cannot pass `null` value to bigDecimal constructor. Wrap my code around `try-catch` to catch the exception.

Comment: Caveat, for other locales this will fail

Answer (score 8):

Remove the dollar sign ($) first.

Comment: A dollar is not a big decimal these days

Comment: @Pediatric What a strange answer without no suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

The constructor requires a Number in the string, your string starts with a `$`, which is not a valid number. You need to strip it out first.